# Kubernetes restarting pods

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, forever

I have containerized node js app running on kubernetes which has volume mounted to host.

For development purpose when there is any change in the host volume dir / files the node app should restart.

In Dockerfile i have

```
CMD ["forever", "index.js"]
```

This will just start the app when container starts, but it is not restarting when the change occurs.

I have cross checked and made sure that changes are syncing properly from host volume to container

Answer (score 2):

`forever` needs a flag to restart on file changes. Try with:

```
CMD ["forever", "-w", "index.js"]
```

I tend to use `nodemon` in development because it watches file changes by default and won't try to restart the app if it fails (only a file change triggers a start), `forever` will try to restart forever.